# How to construct an operator with an infinite spectrum?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. How to construct a bounded operator $T\in B(X)$ such that $\sigma(T)$ is infinite, that is $ card (\sigma(T))= \infty$ ?
Thank you.

Comment: It is possible in Hilbert spaces. So, I would know if it is possible in an arbitrary Banach space.

Comment: Suppose $\{x_n\}$ are linearly independent and $\{r_n\}$ such that $\sum_n |r_n|<\infty$. Define $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}r_k x_k\otimes x_k$. Then $T_n$ converges to a $T$ and $r_nI-T$ has $x_n$ in its kernel.

Comment: @user463383 What is $x_k\otimes x_k$ in a Banach space?  Even in Hilbert space, you would need the $x_k$ orthogonal to guarantee $Tx_n=r_nx_n$.

Comment: is $T$ bounded ?

Comment: Yes, you can choose $x_n$ such that $\|x_n\otimes x_n\|=1$. So, $\|T\|\leq \sum_n|r_n|$.

Comment: @Aweygan So? Choose the vectors accordingly.

Comment: @user463383 While $x_k\otimes x_k$ can be interpreted as a rank-one operator in a Hilbert space, this does not hold true for Banach spaces.

Comment: Can you help me about this probleme, please ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364931/a-question-about-quasi-nilpotent-operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $x_1\in X$ with $\|x_1\|=1$.  By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists $f_1\in X^*$ with $\|f_1\|=1$ and $f_1(x_1)=1$. Now fix $x_2\in\ker(f_1)$ with $\|x_2\|=1$.  By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there is some $f_2\in X^*$ with $\|f_2\|=1$, $f_2(x_2)=1$, and $f_2(x_1)=0$.

Proceeding by induction, for each $n$ obtain $x_n\in\bigcap_{k=1}^{n-1}\ker(f_n)$ with $\|x_n\|=1$ and some $f_n\in X^*$ with $\|f_n\|=1$, $f_n(x_n)=1$ and $f_n(x_k)=0$ for $1\leq k<n$.

For each $n$, define $T_n\in B(X)$ by
$$T_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n2^{-k}f_k(x)x_k.$$
For each $x$, the sequence $\{T_n(x)\}$ is clearly convergent, so by the Banach-Steinhaus the sequence $\{T_n\}$ is pointwise convergent to some $T\in B(X)$.  For each $k$, the sequence $\{T_n(x_k)\}$ is eventually $2^{-k}x_k$, so $T(x_k)=2^{-k}x_k$. Thus 
$$\{2^{-k}:k\in\mathbb N\}\subset\sigma(T),$$
and therefore $\sigma(T)$ is infinite.